# Spring Boot Security with custom auth & session storage

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying simple Spring Boot applications for a Single Page Application, Vue, where the web server is supposed to answer all `/api`, `/auth/login` and `/auth/logout` requests without any views, just JSON responses, like a REST API.

To keep things simple for now, I want a username & password auhtentication, but invoked by Vue frontend. When I use `.formLogin()`, Spring Security creates a cookie with `JSESSIONID`, but it's probably in-memory.

Sorry if the questions is out of place, but I always find conflicting methodologies and quickly get lost due to my lack of knowledge:

1. Is Spring Session is required or not, or how can I extend it to store in a custom repository I own?
2. Is `formLogin()` the correct choice, or should I be using something else?

Comment: Let's see the code of your backend, especially your security-configuration file

Answer (score 1):

1. Spring Session dependency ([org.springframework.session:spring-session-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.session/spring-session-core/2.4.2)) is not required to be manually added to classpath, because it is done by Spring Security. However, if you would like to customize session management, for example change default in memory `SessionRepository` class or session cookie name, then you should add it.
2. `formLogin` is one of the correct choices, but you need to configure it in order to replace default spring security behaviors. Like in [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/), configure `HttpSecurity` bean in order to change default `/login` and `/logout` endpoint paths with yours `/auth/login` and `/auth/logout` values. There are also other things you probably want to configure in this bean, for example adding [authenticationEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExceptionHandlingConfigurer.html#authenticationEntryPoint-org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint-) in [exceptionHandling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#exceptionHandling--) configuration, so you API server responds with 401 http status instead of redirecting to login page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any alternatives to formLogin to have a custom JSON POST body, not a x-form-encoded?

Comment: I doubt there is a standard solution which accepts credentials from json body. The closest thing in spring-security I can think of is httpBasic, so you can send any api request as json body and the request is authorized using Authorization header, which stores user's credentials. If sending credentials in request body as json in order to authenticate user is your requirement, then probably you have to implement it on your own